# Safari 13.1 web inspector not attaching simulator

Tags: debugging, ios-simulator, ionic4, safari-web-inspector

I am facing issue in debugging my ionic 4 app using Safari 13.1.
When I go to develop menu, I can see the simulator appearing. However when I select the simulator, Web inspector does not show any log, reload button or elements

Comment: In case someone is facing same issue, please use simulator version 13+. Changing the simulator (13.2.2) solved my problem.